# Getting a specific id using jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, checkbox

I've a code which is like that :

```
<div class="answer_id" value="1" name="false">
  <input id="AsnwerAnswer1" type="checkbox" value="1" name="true"></input>
  Answer 1
</div>
```

I've 4 answers that are like the code above, the only thing that change is the value in my div and the input id's.

When I click on a checkbox the selected checkbox get the value true :

```
$("input:checkbox").click(function() {
     var thisChecked = $(this)[0].checked;
        $("input:checkbox").removeAttr('checked');
        $("input:checkbox").attr('name', 'false');
        $(this).attr('name', 'true');
        $(this)[0].checked = thisChecked ? true : false;
 });
```

When I click on the button to send the answer :

```
$('#sendReponse').click(function(){
```

I would like to get the value of the div that contains the selected checkbox (the one who has its value at true).

What should I add to this :

```
var iReponseId = $(this).closest('.answer_id').attr('value');
```

By the way it would be really great if you could help me understand what the click function does.
According to me, this remove all the atrributes checked so I can only get one checkbox selected, this set the name to every checkbox to false expect for the one that is selected but I don't understand this :

```
 $(this)[0].checked = thisChecked ? true : false;
```

EDIT :

I did this to get what I wanted :

```
    $("input:checkbox").click(function() {
        $("input:checkbox").not(this).prop('checked',false).removeAttr('class', 'chosen_answer');
        $(this).attr('class', 'chosen_answer');
    });
```

And then

```
 $('#sendReponse').click(function(){
 var iReponseId = $('.chosen_answer').closest('.answer_id').attr('value');
```

Comment: `$(this)[0].checked;` === `this.checked;`

Comment: `$(this)[0].checked = thisChecked ? true : false;`  is rollbacks to your previous state after removing the checked property .... you can reduce that by `this.checked = thisChecked`

Comment: Why all this code, when the radio button was invented for this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your code `$(this)[0].checked = thisChecked ? true : false;`  is helps to rollbacks your previous state of checked property after removing the checked property, it can be reduced as `this.checked = thisChecked`.

---

You can reduce your entire code as follows

```
// use change event always for chekbox
$("input:checkbox").change(function() {
    // get all checkbox
    $("input:checkbox")
         .not(this) // ignore the clicked checkbox
         .prop('checked',false) // uncheck the checkbox 
         .attr('name', 'false'); // set the attribute
    $(this).attr('name', 'true'); // set name of clicked 
});
```

---

For getting the div which contains the input, you need to use `answer_id` class not `response_id`.

```
var iReponseId = $(this).closest('.answer_id').attr('value');
```

---

**FYI :** While using custom attribute always use standard [`data-*`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/Guide/HTML/Using_data_attributes) format.

Comment: In my code this was response I just translated it so at the moment I've the same code as you, the problem is that this part of the code is not in the click function, this is in the case I click on the button to send the answer. I can't have this two working together because if the user click on answer A, then B, then A etc. my ajax takes hours to work.

Comment: @JulienS : allow user to click only after ajax success

Comment: I can't do that, if you have an other way to explore that would be good too. The thing is that I've a survey, when someone click on an answer I've to keep this info so when the person will confirm his choice by clicking on "Send answer" with some ajax it will return the results.

Comment: What do you mean by them? The answers? There is only one answer possible which is why I uncheck all answers when the user check another one.

Comment: @JulienS : are you calling ajax on each change?

Comment: Only on the click on the send button. But when an user has clicked several times the process is taking too long and is wrong.

Comment: The click I'm talking about is the choice of the answer on the checkboxes

Comment: @JulienS : why should you need to send on each click?

Comment: I don't send anything on each click I just want to get the id of the last answer selected. And once the person has made his choice (he can click 10 times on A then B then C etc), after that I still have only one selected answer that I can see in my div name or something like that. And THEN, when the person click on the send button I get the Id of the last selected answer id :) (I'm probably really bad to explain things, sorry)

Comment: I edited my code, that was pretty simple sorry for the trouble, you helped me a lot !

Comment: @JulienS : Ok I got it... but you can't make it fast(I mean the ajax call.. it may depend the network spped and server speed etc).... istead try to send all answer together atlast...

Comment: @JulienS : glad to help you